# RXSwift why loading variable return wrong value?

Tags: rx-swift

Here is my view model:

```
    let loadMoreTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let refreshTrigger = PublishSubject<Void>()
    let loading = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
    let stories = BehaviorRelay<[Story]>(value: [])
    var offset = 0
    let error = PublishSubject<String>()
    let selectedFeedType: BehaviorRelay<FeedType> = BehaviorRelay(value: .best)

   override init() {
    super.init()
    let refreshRequest = loading.asObservable().sample(refreshTrigger).flatMap { loading -> Observable<[Story]> in
        if loading {
            return Observable.empty()
        } else {
            self.offset = 0
            return self.fetchStories(type: self.selectedFeedType.value, offset: self.offset)
        }
    }
    let loadMoreRequest = loading.asObservable().sample(loadMoreTrigger).flatMap { loading -> Observable<[Story]> in
        if loading {
            return Observable.empty()
        } else {
            self.offset += 10
            return self.fetchStories(type: self.selectedFeedType.value, offset: self.offset)
        }
    }
    let request = Observable.merge(refreshRequest, loadMoreRequest).share(replay: 1)
    
    let response = request.flatMap { (stories) -> Observable<[Story]> in
        request.do(onError: { error in
            self.error.onNext(error.localizedDescription)
        }).catchError { (error) -> Observable<[Story]> in
            Observable.empty()
        }
    }.share(replay: 1)
    
    Observable.combineLatest(request, response, stories.asObservable()) { request, response, stories in
        return self.offset == 0 ? response : stories + response
    }.sample(response).bind(to: stories).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    
    Observable.merge(request.map{_ in true}, response.map{_ in false}, error.map{_ in false}).bind(to: loading).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Then when i checking loading observer i have false -> true, instead of true -> false. I just don't understand why it happening.

```
    loading.subscribe {
        print($0)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In my viewController i call refreshTrigger on viewWillAppear using rx.sentMessage

Here is getFeed function:

```
func getFeed(type: FeedType, offset: Int) -> Observable<[Story]> {
    return provider.rx.request(.getFeed(type: type, offset: offset)).asObservable().flatMap { (response) -> Observable<[Story]> in
        do {
            let feedResponse = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(BaseAPIResponse<[Story]>.self, from: response.data)
            guard let stories = feedResponse.data else { return .error(APIError.requestFailed)}
            return .just(stories)
        } catch {
            return .error(error)
        }
    }.catchError { (error) -> Observable<[Story]> in
        return .error(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your `fetchStories(type:offset:)` function which you didn't show. Based on your description, it's emitting a value immediately rather than waiting until the stories are fetched.

Comment: Also, as an FYI... You are making this view model much more complex than it needs to be. I suggest you read more tutorials and/or get on the [RxSwift Slack](http://slack.rxswift.org) where you can get more personalized instruction.

Comment: I've added my getFeed function. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `request` and `response` observables are emitting values at the exact same time. Which one shows up in your subscribe first is undefined.

Specifically, `request` doesn't emit a value until after the fetch request completes. Try this instead:

```
Observable.merge(
    loadMoreTrigger.map { true },
    refreshTrigger.map { true },
    response.map { _ in false },
    error.map { _ in false }
)
.bind(to: loading)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

There are lots of other problems in your code but the above answers this specific question.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your answer! Your suggestion is working, but I’m interested in how can I managed to create my view model in the right way? I need simply refresh observable handling by refresherControl loadMore when table reached bottom, and loading observable to check when data is loading (I’ve already did this) but I wonder how can I improve the logic.

Comment: That's why I recommended the RxSwift Slack. Stack Overflow is great for specific questions but not so good for general advice. As I mentioned in a previous answer to you, `Subject`s are not a general purpose type and don't need to be used nearly as much as you have here. Rx is functional. Notice in your view model how almost all of the code is in the `init()`? Instead of thinking of the view model as a class, think of it as a single function that takes a number of Observables as inputs and returns Observables. Come to the slack channel and learn about the philosophy behind Rx.

Comment: @BobbyRedjeans Another option would be to post your working code on the  [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site. Answers there tend to be about more efficient ways to do things rather than answers to problems you are having.